# docker build: Returned a non-zero code: 5

Tags: python-3.x, docker, dockerfile

I wonna run this (https://github.com/thomashossler/synthetic-data-generator#config-file) project and I can't build the docker image.
I didn't find this error on stackoverflow so i hope you can help me

```
/synthetic-data-generator$ docker build . -f Dockerfile 
Sending build context to Docker daemon  3.944MB
Step 1/11 : FROM python:3.6
 ---> 0668df180a32
Step 2/11 : RUN apt-get update &&     apt-get install -y         
bzip2         git         git-core         libfontconfig1         
libgconf-2-4         libglu1         libsm6         libxext6         
libxrender1         vim         wget
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 0c92c577bdf4
Step 3/11 : WORKDIR /root/
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 2221c959662d
Step 4/11 : RUN wget -c --quiet 
download.blender.org/release/Blender2.79/blender-2.79a-linux- 
glibc219-x86_64.tar.bz2 &&     tar -xf blender-2.79a-linux-glibc219- 
x86_64.tar.bz2 &&     rm blender-2.79a-linux-glibc219-x86_64.tar.bz2 
&&     mv blender-2.79a-linux-glibc219-x86_64/ blender/ &&     cp -r 
blender /usr/lib/blender &&     echo "export 
PATH="/usr/lib/blender:$PATH"" >> /root/.bashrc
 ---> Running in 03a48a002fe6
The command '/bin/sh -c wget -c --quiet 
download.blender.org/release/Blender2.79/blender-2.79a-linux- 
glibc219-x86_64.tar.bz2 &&     tar -xf blender-2.79a-linux-glibc219- 
x86_64.tar.bz2 &&     rm blender-2.79a-linux-glibc219-x86_64.tar.bz2 
&&     mv blender-2.79a-linux-glibc219-x86_64/ blender/ &&     cp -r 
blender /usr/lib/blender &&     echo "export 
PATH="/usr/lib/blender:$PATH"" >> /root/.bashrc' returned a non-zero 
code: 5
```

my Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.6

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y \
        bzip2 \
        git \
        git-core \
        libfontconfig1 \
        libgconf-2-4 \
        libglu1 \
        libsm6 \
        libxext6 \
        libxrender1 \
        vim \
        wget

WORKDIR /root/
RUN wget -c --quiet 
download.blender.org/release/Blender2.79/blender-2.79a-linux- 
   glibc219-x86_64.tar.bz2 && \
tar -xf blender-2.79a-linux-glibc219-x86_64.tar.bz2 && \
rm blender-2.79a-linux-glibc219-x86_64.tar.bz2 && \
mv blender-2.79a-linux-glibc219-x86_64/ blender/ && \
cp -r blender /usr/lib/blender && \
echo "export PATH="/usr/lib/blender:$PATH"" >> /root/.bashrc


COPY /src/requirements.txt /root
RUN pip3 install -r /root/requirements.txt

RUN pip3 install --user 
git+https://github.com/cocodataset/cocoapi.git#subdirectory=PythonAPI

COPY models /root/models/
COPY src /root/
COPY deploy/config.json /root/

CMD ["python3", "dataset_creation.py"]
# ENTRYPOINT ["/root/entrypoint.sh"]
#EXPOSE 8889
#CMD ["jupyter notebook", "--ip=0.0.0.0", "--allow-root", "--port=8889"]
```

Can anyone have similar experience and give me an solution. Very appreciated!

Comment: What have you already tried to do to debug this?  (For instance, breaking up the `RUN` command into multiples helps.)  Have you looked at other SO questions about contexts where `.bashrc` isn’t read at all?

Answer (score 7):

It is most likely failing on the `wget` command.  That RUN line has 6 separate commands.  The other 5 would all likely produce some error message if they failed.  The `wget` has the `--quiet` flag passed which is suppressing output.

To debug further, try removing the `--quiet` flag from the `wget`.

From `man wget`, EXIT STATUS of 5 = SSL verification error.  Perhaps you are behind a corporate proxy and do not have the SSL certs installed in the container that is running the wget.

Answer (score 1):

For me using the wget parameter "--no-check-certificate" removed the SSL error. I assume because you do not have a valid certificate store in the build process environment, wget cannot check if the certificate from a https connection is valid.

Comment: thanks this worked for me when using opkg i was getting this wget error and the --no-check-certificate flag solved the problem.